# R plotly - radar plot legend

Tags: r, plotly, legend, radar-chart, spider-chart

I’m having a new problem in the legend of the radar plot after changing the colors of each group.

The legend shows the name of each group (which is correct) but it also shows the color name (the rgb code).

It looks like this:

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSenN.png)

Is it possible to only show the group names?

I'll leave a reproducible example:

```
attrib1 <- c( 2, 3, 5)
attrib2 <- c( 1, 2, 5)
attrib3 <- c( 5, 2, 4)
attrib4 <- c( 4, 3, 1)
attrib5 <- c( 2, 2, 1)


teams_final <- data.frame(attrib1, attrib2, attrib3, attrib4, attrib5, attrib1)

row.names(teams_final) <- c("A Team", "B Team", "C Team")

labels <- c("attrib1", "attrib2", "attrib3", "attrib4", "attrib5", "attrib1")


library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
    type = 'scatterpolar', fill = 'toself') %>%

    add_trace(r = unname(teams_final[1, ]), theta = labels, name = "A Team", 
              fillcolor = 'rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5)', marker = list(color = '#404040'),
              hoverinfo = "text", 
              text = ~paste(labels, '<br> Importance: ', unname(teams_final[1, ]))) %>%

    add_trace(r = unname(teams_final[2, ]), theta = labels, name = "B Team",
              fillcolor = 'rgba(171, 35, 35, 0.5)', marker = list(color = '#AB2323'), 
              hoverinfo = "text", 
              text = ~paste(labels, '<br> Importance: ', unname(teams_final[1, ]))) %>%

    add_trace(r = unname(teams_final[3, ]), theta = labels, name = "C Team",
              fillcolor = 'rgba(241, 103, 69, 0.5)', marker = list(color = '#F16745'), 
              hoverinfo = "text", 
              text = ~paste(labels, '<br> Importance: ', unname(teams_final[1, ]))) %>%

    layout(polar = list(radialaxis = list(visible = T, range = c(0,6))), 
         font = list(size = 11, color = "#202020"))

p
```

Cheers,

Bruno

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: it might be a bug?

Comment: Maybe... I've posted it also in the official plotly community but didn't get an answer yet